# pyvirtual display and xvfb on MacOS latest

Tags: python-3.x, xvfb

#### Context

I am trying to get some code working on MacOS. The code uses the Mayavi visualization library, and is supposed to run on headless servers to produce visualizations.

#### Dependencies

```bash
brew install gdal
brew install xdpyinfo
brew install --cask xquartz
```

And then I install the desired library:

```bash
python3 -m pip install PyVirtualDisplay
```

But this does not seem to work on the Github Action remote:

##### The error:

```
  display = Display(visible=0, size=(1280, 1024))
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py:54: in __init__
    self._obj = cls(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py:44: in __init__
    AbstractDisplay.__init__(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/abstractdisplay.py:85: in __init__
    helptext = get_helptext(program)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/util.py:13: in get_helptext
    p = subprocess.Popen(
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:951: in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:1821: in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
E   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Xvfb'
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR test_animate.py - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or director...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================== 1 error in 27.12s ===============================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
brew install --cask xquartz

# in your ~/.zshrc
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/X11/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the github workflow defined by [PyVirtualDisplay](https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml), the solution was to execute the following (for a github action):

```bash
    - name: Install MacOS dependencies
      if: startsWith(matrix.os, 'macos')
      run: |
        brew install --cask xquartz
        # https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path
        echo "/opt/X11/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH  
        # https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay/issues/42
        mkdir /tmp/.X11-unix
        sudo chmod 1777 /tmp/.X11-unix
        sudo chown root /tmp/.X11-unix
```